# Java variable initialization in if-then statement

Tags: java, android, if-statement, wifi

I have this code that is suppose to turn off Wifi via a toggle button. I also want to have it so that if the user already had Wifi on before pressing the button, the Wifi would go back on after turning off the toggle button. This is done through the wifiON `boolean`. However, since the variable is initialized in the first part of the if statement, it won't be used by the else statement. How can I set it so that the else statement can get the value of the boolean from the if statement. Below is the code.

```
    public void airplaneClicked (View view) {
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    boolean wifiOn;

    if (on) {
        if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
            wifiOn = true;
            Log.v("", "" + wifiOn);
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
        } else {
            wifiOn = false;
            Log.v("", "" + wifiOn);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (wifiOn == true) {
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: declare a global static variable for it... It should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wifi.setWifiEnabled(!wifi.isWifiEnabled());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the value of `wifiOn` in both parts of the if-else, move it to be before the if-else.

```
if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
    wifiOn = true;
} else {
    wifiOn = false;
}
if (on) {
    if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
        Log.v("", "" + wifiOn);
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
    } else {
        Log.v("", "" + wifiOn);
    }
}
else {
    if (wifiOn == true) {
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but the problem is that I need to capture the state of the wifi right before the user turns on the button. When I use your method wifiOn will always be set to false because it'll call the method .isWifiEnabled after wifi.setWifiEnabled(false) has happened.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Use additional boolean - wifiState

boolean wifiState = wifi.isWifiEnabled(); 
        if (on) {
                if (wifiState) {
                    wifiState = true;
                    Log.v("", "" + wifiOn);
                    wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    wifiState = false;
                    Log.v("", "" + wifiOn);
                }
            }
            else {
                if (wifiState) {
                    wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I need the wifiState value to save from the if (on) statement and be used in the else statement.